# Paypal ManagePendingTransactionStatus method returning error

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to cancel a pending transaction via PayPal's Classic API (SOAP) using the ManagePendingTransactionStatus method, but the response is always an internal error. I have already tried to change the `Action`, `DetailLevel`, `Version`, and I've used various  (existing) `TransactionID`s, but nothing worked.

Have someone passed through something alike? Is there some configuration I'm missing?

I'm using the sandbox environment, from my ASP.NET WebForms (framework version 4.5) app, within my localhost on Windows 7 x64. Here are the request content:

URL: https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/

Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cc="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes" xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:ed="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes" xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <ns:RequesterCredentials>
            <ebl:Credentials>
                <ebl:Username>correct.username</ebl:Username>
                <ebl:Password>correct.password</ebl:Password>
                <ebl:Signature>Correct.Signature</ebl:Signature>
            </ebl:Credentials>
        </ns:RequesterCredentials>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns:ManagePendingTransactionStatusReq>
            <ns:ManagePendingTransactionStatusRequest>
                <ebl:Version>104.0</ebl:Version>
                <ns:TransactionID>3B880366F0154954J</ns:TransactionID>
                <ns:Action>Deny</ns:Action>
            </ns:ManagePendingTransactionStatusRequest>
        </ns:ManagePendingTransactionStatusReq>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:cc="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:ed="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes" xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xsi:type="wsse:SecurityType"></Security>
        <RequesterCredentials xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xsi:type="ebl:CustomSecurityHeaderType">
            <Credentials xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xsi:type="ebl:UserIdPasswordType">
                <Username xsi:type="xs:string"></Username>
                <Password xsi:type="xs:string"></Password>
                <Signature xsi:type="xs:string"></Signature>
                <Subject xsi:type="xs:string"></Subject>
            </Credentials>
        </RequesterCredentials>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body id="_0">
        <ManagePendingTransactionStatusResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
            <Timestamp xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">2014-05-28T14:27:44Z</Timestamp>
            <Ack xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">Failure</Ack>
            <CorrelationID xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">1c49de851e39e</CorrelationID>
            <Errors xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xsi:type="ebl:ErrorType">
                <ShortMessage xsi:type="xs:string">Internal Error</ShortMessage>
                <LongMessage xsi:type="xs:string">Internal Error</LongMessage>
                <ErrorCode xsi:type="xs:token">10001</ErrorCode>
                <SeverityCode xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">Error</SeverityCode>
            </Errors>
            <Version xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">104.0</Version>
            <Build xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">10958405</Build>
            <TransactionID xsi:type="xs:string">3B880366F0154954J</TransactionID>
            <Status xsi:type="xs:string">The Status of the transaction after running the your action (accept/deny) is:Unable To Determine</Status>
        </ManagePendingTransactionStatusResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, The ManagePendingTransactionStatus API operation accepts or denys a pending transaction **held by Fraud Management Filters.** If it is pending for any other reason the operation will likely produce an error.

Comment: Isn't the "Payment review" feature in the sandbox env. equivalent to FMF? If not, how can I simulate an FMF block?

Comment: No, Payment review is initiated by PayPal and FMF is initiated by you. Check out the following page: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_error-conditions/.  It talks about negative testing which allows you to simulate errors.

Comment: Hi, Kevin. The Negative Testing mode, as I understood it, makes PayPal return a specific error - and, consequently, the `Ack` property equals `Failure`. What I really need is to receive a `SuccessWithWarning`, and a `PaymentStatus` of `Pending`. I can achieve this with the "Payment review" feature, but what I'm really trying to accomplish is to deny a pending transaction via API. Are there any means to do that within the sandbox env.?

Comment: I did some research on the issue. It's possible to add FMF (Advanced Fraud Filters) to a PayPal sandbox account but it appears you need someone at PayPal to enable it. I used one of my own sandbox accounts to test this and I was successful. If you wish to have FMF added to one of your sandbox accounts my suggestion would be to file a ticket with Merchant Technical Services and ask them to enable it. you'll need to give them the email address of the sandbox account. www.paypal.com/mts